# How should i fix my error in gradle sincing?

Tags: android, gradle

unfortunately i got this error when the gradle was syncing,

Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar

here is my build.Gradle page details,

```
buildscript {

repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `gradlePluginPortal()`

```
buildscript {

repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

then Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Nothing happend

Comment: Nobody know?if know please help i searched alot but nothing happend